# php getting value from DIV tag

Tags: php, html, tags

I have a code like this.

```
<form id="mainForm" method="post" action="">
<div id="info">6.897882999999999, 79.92221100000006</div>
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

**I want to assign div tag value** *(6.897882999999999, 79.92221100000006)* **to php variable using div id** . Is it possible. if yes, how to do this. thanks

Comment: you "have" code like this? where? rendered in the browser? as a string in your code? in a file on the filesystem?

Comment: it's in a form and i have a submit button called submit

Comment: why not make it a textbox so you can just submit it and get the value?

Comment: I'm using this code for web application. It's not nice to have text box here. That's why im using this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Alternatives: [Robust and Mature HTML Parser for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php)

Comment: I'm assuming you've picked the first link as your implementation. What are you getting stuck on in the tutorial?

Comment: how to assign value to php variable ?

Comment: Suggested third party alternatives to [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) that actually use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead of String Parsing: [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html), [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) and [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org). See [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)